# Embedding of co-oriented subspaces into positive Grassmannian

Tags: linear-algebra, grassmannians, total-positivity

$\def\R{\mathbb{R}}$Let $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ be three $m$-dimensional subspaces in $\R^n$. With a slight abuse of notation they will also denote the ortho-projectors on the respective subspaces. We shall assume that they are in generic relative position, i.e. no subspace contains a vector that is orthogonal to any other subspace, which is equivalent to $P_i: P_k \rightarrow P_i$ being an isomorphism of $P_k$ onto $P_i$, for any choice of $i$, $k$.

We shall use the orthoprojectors $P_i$ to synchronize orientation of bases in the subspaces. Namely, we say that the triple $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ is co-oriented if for any distinct $i, j, k$ the map
$$ P_i P_j P_k P_i: P_i \rightarrow P_i$$
has positive determinant.

When $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ all belong to the positive Grassmannian they are automatically co-oriented (this, for example, follows from the Cauchy–Binet formula).

> My question is whether the reverse is true, i.e. if $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ are co-oriented whether there exists an orthonormal basis in $\R^n$ such that each $P_k$ belongs to the positive Grassmannian associated with that basis.

Comment: MathJax note: when you define a command using `$\newcommand\macro{text}$`, *don't* follow it with a blank (or else leave do not end the math environment until after the blank).  Otherwise, there will be a spurious blank line in your question.  I have edited accordingly.